# ARKit does not recognize reference images

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit

I'm trying to place a 3D model on top of a recognized image with ARKit and RealityKit - all programmatically. Before I start the ARView I'm downloading the model I want to show when the reference image is detected.

This is my current setup:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    arView.session.delegate = self
    
    // Check if the device supports the AR experience
    if (!ARConfiguration.isSupported) {
        TLogger.shared.error_objc("Device does not support Augmented Reality")
        return
    }
    
    guard let qrCodeReferenceImage = UIImage(named: "QRCode") else { return }
    let detectionImages: Set<ARReferenceImage> = convertToReferenceImages([qrCodeReferenceImage])
    
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.detectionImages = detectionImages
    
    arView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
}
```

I use the ARSessionDelegate to get notified when a new image anchor was added which means the reference image got detected:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    print("Hello")
    for anchor in anchors {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
        let referenceImage = imageAnchor.referenceImage
        
        addEntity(self.localModelPath!)
    }
}
```

However, the delegate method never gets called while other delegate functions like `func session(ARSession, didUpdate: ARFrame)`  are getting called so I assume that the session just doesn't detect the image. The image resolution is good and the printed image the big so it should definitely get recognized by the ARSession. I also checked that the image has been found before adding it to the configuration.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction here?

Comment: Have you tried to add the image to the project to see if it works? The AR Resources folder would warn you if the image is not a good candidate for recognition.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your configuration set up correctly. Your delegate-function should be called when the reference image is recognized. Make sure your configuration isn't overwritten at any point in your code.

Comment: The configuration was actually overwritten by the viewWillAppear function. I have no idea why it got executed after viewDidLoad but after I removed the viewWillAppear function from my code the issue was resolved.

Comment: This is not an answer, you're asking a question back to OP, should have been a comment

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It's my first reply to a question, I'm quite new to the community. I changed my last sentence to a suggestion.